Statistics for RCTs
What is the best approach to determine whether one treatment has significantly greater effects than another from an RCT?
Word of mouth says there has to be a time x treatment interaction in the model, but I'm not finding much literature supporting this, and a lot of the studies I'm reading focus only on between and within group effects, w/o an interaction. If there are any easy to follow stats papers reviewing approaches to RCT data analysis please share as well!

This is a very broad question.  RCTs come in different varieties, and the analysis will often depend on the design and the goal of the trial.  Are you looking for anything in specific?

@DemetriPananos Hi, we are conducting a systematic review and others on the team are arguing that we should only consider a study "high quality" if it includes the time by treatment interaction. I just can't find any literature clearly stating the best stats for RCTs to agree or disagree with them.

Some clinical trials only collect data at one time point. Many compare survival curves, so there is no concept of interaction. Some compare variables taht are continuous, some compare binary outcomes. Your attempt to make one general rule doesn't make sense, at least not without constraining to certain types of trials.

There is no "one size fits all". In the simplest of cases you may be fine with a t-test. In others you might need a model with covariates - so an ANCOVA or multiple linear regression. In others you might be taking repeated observations from participants, so a model with random effects such as a linear mixed model; or a markov longitudinal ordinal model could be used. In short, if you are doing a systematic review then either you need to limit yourself to a particular design, or you could analyse them in groups where each group uses a particular design.
